# Is there any way to specifically optimize a single output from a neural network in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

For example, if I had a neural network that was playing draughts/checkers and attempted to make an invalid move, is there a way to specifically optimize that particular output?

```
  ---------------------------------------
8 |    | bM |    | bM |    | bM |    | bM | 
  ---------------------------------------
7 | bM |    | bM |    | bM |    | bM |    | 
  ---------------------------------------
6 |    | bM |    | bM |    | bM |    | bM | 
  ---------------------------------------
5 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
  ---------------------------------------
4 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
  ---------------------------------------
3 | wM |    | wM |    | wM |    | wM |    | 
  ---------------------------------------
2 |    | wM |    | wM |    | wM |    | wM | 
  ---------------------------------------
1 | wM |    | wM |    | wM |    | wM |    | 
  ---------------------------------------
    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H
```

If the board were to look like this, and there was an output neuron for every possible move in the realms of a draught piece (up to a movement of 2 in any direction) so 64 * 8 output neurons, if the highest probability output was neuron 8 (or any other invalid output) which would be something like B1C2 (B1 being starting position and C2 being ending position).

Is there a way, if the output of the neural network is already a probability distribution, to update the network so that this particular output is 0 and all the other outputs are updated and normalized?

I've tried looking at examples of neural nets that train on the mnist data set and adamoptimizer but couldn't find anything that only changes one particular output rather than changing the whole output layer.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

For this specific example, you're better off restructuring your network to only include moves that could potentially be valid. B1C2 will never be a valid move, so don't let that be a part of your network.

For moves that could potentially be valid but aren't actually valid, such as B2C3 (not valid for the first turn but valid after moving the piece currently on C3), you can write a custom activation function, but it will probably be easier to just adjust the output.

You can write a function to set each invalid move to zero, and then you will divide all the other answers by (1 - sum of invalid move predictions). Note that this assumes that you are already using softmax as your last activation function.

**Edit based on follow up question below:**

You can write one function that takes the board state and predictions as input and returns the predictions with invalid moves set to zero and the rest of the predictions normalized.

If instead of modifying the end result you rather have the network learn which moves are invalid, that can be handled by your loss function. For instance, if you are doing deep Q learning then you would add a heavy penalty to the score for invalid moves.

Comment: Wouldn't I then have to write a different function depending completely on the board state to start with? Is there anyway to backpropogate for the particular output chosen as this would mean that it would mean in other similar situations it's less likely to pick the same invalid move. (Hence learning that invalid moves are invalid)